# How can I use Ansible nested variable?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have an Ansible playbook like the one below, I want use nested variable like this:
`msg={{{{Component}}.community_release_num}}`, but when I run playbook:

```
ansible-playbook vartest.yml -e 'version=version_402', it not work 

[es@vpn-server nested-var]$ tree
.
├── vars
│   ├── horizon.yml
│   └── version_402.yml
└── vartest.yml

1 directory, 3 files
[es@vpn-server nested-var]$ cat vartest.yml 
---

- name: test 
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - vars/{{version}}.yml
  tasks:
    - debug: msg={{{{Component}}.community_release_num}}
    - debug: msg={{{{Component}}.release_num}}

[es@vpn-server nested-var]$ cat vars/horizon.yml 
Component: horizon

[es@vpn-server nested-var]$ cat vars/version_402.yml 
- horizon:
   community_release_num: '9.0.1'
   release_num: '4.0.2'
[es@vpn-server nested-var]$
```

error messages

```
[es@vpn-server nested-var]$ ansible-playbook vartest.yml -e 'version=version_402'
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/cryptography/__init__.py:25: DeprecationWarning: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python.
  DeprecationWarning

PLAY [test] *******************************************************************************************************
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py:57: PowmInsecureWarning: Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.
  _warn("Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.", PowmInsecureWarning)

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'colon', got '}'. String: {{{{Component}}.community_release_num}}"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/data/wangqian/artemis-code-test/artemis/ansible/update/nested-var/vartest.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Can Ansible use nested variable, if yes, how to use it?

Answer (score 40):

Per [Ansible FAQ](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names):

> Another rule is ‘moustaches don’t stack’. We often see this:
>
> ```
> {{ somevar_{{other_var}} }}
> ```
>
> The above DOES NOT WORK, if you need to use a dynamic variable use the
>   hostvars or vars dictionary as appropriate:
>
> ```
> {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['somevar_' + other_var] }}
> ```

So in your case:

```
- debug: msg={{hostvars[inventory_hostname][Component].community_release_num}}
```

Or:

```
- debug: msg={{vars[Component].community_release_num}}
```

Or (since Ansible 2.5):

```
- debug: msg={{(lookup('vars', Component)).community_release_num}}
```

Comment: how can this be done. ```region: 1 dev1_ips: 1,2  {{ dev[region]_ips }}```

Comment: @SNR `{{ lookup('vars', 'dev' ~ region ~ '_ips') }}`

Comment: @SNR Also note the `~`. In your example you gave numbers. `+` would work if it was `region: "1"`. Otherwise `"Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ lookup('vars', 'dev' + region + '_ips') }}): can only concatenate str (not \"int\") to str"`. But `~` works in both cases. See https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#other-operators for details.

Comment: Understood Thanks @JasmineHegman

Answer (score 1):

Run this command:
ansible-playbook 1_lambda-facts.yml -e "func_name=mylambdaFunctionName"

```
- name: get lamda Info
   hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   become: yes
   gather_facts: true
   tasks:
   - name: List all for a specific function
     lambda_facts:
       query: all
       function_name: "{{func_name}}"
    
   - name: debug info
     debug:
       msg: "{{lambda_facts}}"
       msg: "variable name is: {{vars['func_name']}}"
       msg: "{{lambda_facts['function'][vars['func_name']]['function_arn']}}"
```