# Ansible Variable Filters and Expansion

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to debug a variable that is being filtered, and my debug statement contains a second nested variable. I can't seem to find the proper format to get the debug working.

For example:

```
  vars:
    - bw_type: as
    - patches: [
        PB.ps.21.sp1.551.pb2017091592773,
        PB.as.21.sp1.551.pb2017091555706,
        PB.as.21.sp1.551.pb2017091555707,
        PB.xsp.21.sp1.551.pb2017091891314 ]
```

`- debug: msg="Deployments - {{ patches|select('match','PB.{{ bw_type }}.')|list }}"`

I understand that I can simply remove the debug msg and execute against the var, and that works fine. Example -

`- debug: var=patches|select('match','PB.{{ bw_type }}.')|list`

But I can't do the same in a with_items scenario due to outter moustache being required, therefore I'm trying to get this working.

I've read over a previous post here [How can I use Ansible nested variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46209556/how-can-i-use-ansible-nested-variable)

but I'm not sure how to apply this with the filtering I have in place. In light of that post I've also tried the following with no success.

```
- debug: msg=" Deployments - {{ vars[patches|select('match','PB.'+ bw_type +'.')|list] }}"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jinja2 syntax:

```
- debug:
    msg: "Deployments - {{ patches | select('match', 'PB.' + bw_type + '.') | list }}"
```

<sup>The post you referenced is about using a variable in another variable's name. That is a different problem than yours.</sup>

Comment: Nice, Thank You!