# Nested jinja2 dns queries

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to build an rsyslog configuration using jinja2 templating in Ansible. To separate the logs by device, I created the following template to generate an rsyslog config entry for each device, which are saved in an Ansible inventory, with the right location to save the logs:

```
{% for device in groups["devices"] %}
$template device_{{ device }},"/var/log/devices/{{ device }}/%timegenerated:1:10:date-rfc3339%"
if $fromhost-ip = '{{ lookup('dig', '{{ device }}.example.org') }}' then ?device_{{ device }}
{% endfor %}
```

Finally I want to get a config that would contain for example:

```
$template device_raspi,"/var/log/devices/raspi/%timegenerated:1:10:date-rfc3339%"
if $fromhost-ip = '10.2.3.4' then ?device_raspi       # with 10.2.3.4 as IP of raspi
```

But while execution the second variable of the DNS lookup (that one with the example.org) triggers the following error:

`fatal: [logging]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'device' is undefined"}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Ansible nested variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46209556/how-can-i-use-ansible-nested-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that you cannot nest `{{ }}` as you have done here:

`'{{ lookup('dig', '{{ device }}.example.org') }}'`

---

You can instead do this, and `device` should be parsed correctly:

`'{{ lookup('dig', device + '.example.org') }}'`