# Jinja templating of lists in Ansible vars files without 'max recursion depth reached' or blank items

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm having the following problem templating an ansible vars file that's included in my role in the two following specific ways and I'm wondering if there's a correct way to do this, or if it's just something ansible can't do out of the box due to yaml parser limitations. Best thoughts are appreciated.

Please note the constraint that I'm working entirely with a vars include for this, I am well aware I could include tasks and build the logic that way, but that is sub-optimal for my design.

Issue #1: Dynamically setting content with jinja templating in a vars file.

In regard to strings, something like this works really well:

```
fqdn: "{% if condition %}
          .mydomain.io
        {% else %}
          .blah.net
        {% endif %}"
```

However, the issue comes into play when attempting this same logical flow with a list, such as:

```
network_dns: 
  - {% if condition %}8.8.8.8{% endif %}
  - {% if condition %}8.8.4.4{% endif %}
```

This DOES work, but it's messy and it leaves empty list items where the logic isn't met. Not entirely an isse because I tend to go overboard makign sure I trim my list inputs in my roles, but messy. Sadly, it's not always a this or that flow either, and I have some items that would set 3-4 values in a list, meaning that I need 3-4 like conditional lines since I can't set multiple list items in a single list item without creating a sub list. Really looking for what the best method is here.

Issue #2: list recursion 'max recursion depth reached'
More ideally would be something like this:

```
network_dns: "{{ network_dns | d([]) + {% if condition %}['8.8.8.8','8.8.4.4']{% else %}[]{% endif %} }}"
```

or even (but slightly less ideal still) assign a temp var to condition and add multiple values would be better:

```
temp_vars_net_dns: "{% if condition %}['8.8.8.8','8.8.4.4']{% else %}[]{% endif %}"
network_dns: "{{ network_dns | d([]) + temp_vars_net_dns }}"
```

However, whenever I attempt to combine lists like this in a vars file, I always run into a 'max recursion depth reached' issue, because the parser doesn't fully unpack the list var before it appends items, so it recursively iterates through the appended items forever and ever and ever and ever and... well, you get the idea.

Again, not looking for the perfect infallible solution (unless you have it), just looking for something to make this a bit easier to manage in terms of vars organization.

Comment: _max recursion depth reached_: happens because you are trying ti assign a variable to itself, which you cannot. If I reduce your code to the minimal, you'll get: `network_dns: "{{ network_dns }}"`, which creates an assignation loop: to assign `network_dns`, `network_dns` should be expended, which in terms expends `network_dns`, ...

Comment: So this is "unrelated" to your condition. This said, your case is a good fit for inline expression: [`"{{ network_dns | d([]) + ['8.8.8.8','8.8.4.4'] if condition else [] }}"`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#if-expression)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Just to be clear, you absolutley CAN assign a variable to itself in most contexts. For instance, this works a-okay 
```
    - name: Concatenate list2 to list1
      set_fact:
        list1: "{{ list1 + list2 }}"
```

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Even defaults you can do this iirc, THE REASON you cannot add a list to itself in a vars file specifically is a limitation in that parser engine. What happens is that it fails to fully unpack a list before it appends so if you have list1 == [1,2,3] when you try and `list1 = list1`, it ends up in a recursive loop of starting reading through list1 which has a len of 3, then adding list1 to list1, but now list1 is a len of 6, so it continues to loop items 4-6, now list1 has a len of 9, and like this until it gives up.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε and to be clear also, using an inline expression like that is essentially what I'm doing. I just have branching logic so I need to dynamically set values based on a ton of conditionals, for a ton of divergent values. DNS is just the most simple example I could provide. And as it is, I basically am doing that with big monolithic logical blocks, that's what I'm aiming to simplify if there's a way to do so.

Comment: The `set_fact` acts a different way, it evaluates the jinja expression first, then assign it. With a var file, you are getting back to the normal situation and variable are lazy loaded see `set_facts`'s notes: _["Because of the nature of tasks, set_fact will produce ‘static’ values for a variable. Unlike normal ‘lazy’ variables, the value gets evaluated and templated on assignment."](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html#notes)_

Comment: All in all, you have to understand that, `network_dns: "{{ network_dns }}"` does not make sense in Ansible, variables are not something you 'extend' based on its own value, because variables do [take precedence over previous assignation, rather](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). What you are trying to achieve looks more like it should be expressed like `network_dns: "{{ ['8.8.8.8','8.8.4.4'] if condition else [] }}"`.  You could also look into variable composition based on constructed inventories.

Comment: ^-- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/constructed_inventory.html

Comment: neat, but that doesn't solve my issue either sadly. I need to import these in a task and not in host inventory. I almost wonder if it would be more ideal if I were to use j2 template to write out the file to then import, but that seems really hacky and messy.

Answer (score 1):

> This DOES work

It actually should not because it's not a valid YAML. This is a reason why it's recommended to always surround the Jinja templates with quotes.

> but it's messy and it leaves empty list items where the logic isn't met

Easy - there's [`ternary`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ternary_filter.html) filter designed specifically for this case:

```yaml
vars:
  fqdn: "{{ condition | ternary('.mydomain.io', '.blah.net') }}"
```

The same can be applied to `network_dns` variable. I would recommend, however, to define the list of IPs separately to ease the things:

```yaml
vars:
  network_dns_default:
    - 8.8.8.8
    - 8.8.4.4
  network_dns: "{{ condition | ternary(network_dns_default, []) }}"
```

So, no need for if-else - these usually go against Ansible principles of simplicity.

Comment: but this does not accomplish the goal of constructing a list based on a potentially existing list AND allowing for logical deviation in a list. Where, in this basic example, some systems may need to be configured with 8.8.8.8 based on a filter (lets say CIDR), other configured to use 8.8.4.4, some others for say 10.0.0.200, and some configured for multiple sets of those based on logical rule sets.

Comment: The example I'm looking for simplified would realistically look more like this (point conceded on wrapping in quotes, but it does work fine except it ends up with empty list items where the condition is not true): 

network_dns: 
  - "{% if condition 1 %}8.8.8.8{% endif %}"
  - "{% if condition 2 %}8.8.4.4{% endif %}"
  - "{% if condition 3 %}10.0.0.200{% endif %}"
  - "{% if condition 4 %}10.10.0.200{% endif %}"
  - "{% if condition 5 %}10.0.10.200{% endif %}"

Comment: @MikeBauer empty lines are consequence of your attempts to manage the conditions within strings a list instead of conditionally constructing a list of strings. Besides, if you have complex conditions (I treat _many_ conditions as a complex case here), a go-to solution is to build an inventory instead. There you can either group your systems by these conditions manually, or add them to the groups dynamically based on the same conditions. Alternatively, you can just have several `set_facts` tasks with the corresponding `when` conditions.

Comment: Please note the constraint that I'm working entirely with a vars include for this, I am well aware I could include tasks and build the logic that way, but that is sub-optimal for my design, as stated in the original question. 

As well, I'm well aware of why it leaved blank spaces. Nothing about that is a mystery, but thank you for the explanation anyway. The issue isn't that I'm attempting to manage the conditions within strings however, it's that you cannot conditionally append to existing lists.

Answer (score 0):

Whereby I strongly recommend to accept either the [already here given answer with `ternary` filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78169052/6771046) because it is a much less complex one, or investing in research into [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html), the following demonstrate how it would look like with Jinja2 Template and YAML.

For a Jinja2 Template called **`var.file.j2`** with content of

```yaml
network_dns: "{{ network_dns | d([]) + ['8.8.8.8','8.8.4.4'] if CONDITION else [] }}"
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    network_dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 9.9.9.9
    CONDITION: True

  tasks:

  - template:
      src: var.file.j2
      dest: var.file

  - include_vars:
      file: var.file
      name: NET_CONFIG

  - debug:
      var: NET_CONFIG.network_dns
```

will result into an output file **`var.file`** with content of

```yaml
network_dns: "[u'1.1.1.1', u'9.9.9.9', '8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']"
```

and an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************
ok: [localhost] =>
  NET_CONFIG.network_dns:
  - 1.1.1.1
  - 9.9.9.9
  - 8.8.8.8
  - 8.8.4.4
```

As one can see just from this small example, it is already very complex, error prone, not readable as it is not clear where becomes defined what and how, very bad to maintain, and so on ...

So don't do it that way [even if technically possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72448284/6771046) and invest time into research regarding [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html).