# How to parses multiple variables within ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm stuck on parse multiple variables...

How could I parsed two variables in the same time?
Here's the task where I try to get the two variables inside **keep_qry**... **cv_ver_name** is ok but not the **keep_count**. I've tried different things but nothing worked...

```
- name: "Set content view version keep list"
  set_fact:
    cv_keep_list: "{{ keep_qry }}"
  vars:
    keep_count: ":{{ cv.keep_content_view_versions_count }}"
    keep_qry: "{{ cv_ver_names[{{ keep_count }}] }}"
```

Has someone an idea how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance for your support and best regards,
H.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Ansible nested variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46209556/how-can-i-use-ansible-nested-variable) As "_moustaches don’t stack_" you may use `"{{ cv_ver_names[keep_count] }}"` instead.

Comment: I've already tried this syntax but it doesn't run for this case.

Comment: "doesn't run for this case" == "does not work" <= [this does not accurately describe your problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Meanwhile, I just noticed there is a typo in you `keep_count` var (a prepended column in front of the variable expansion) which might be the source of your problem. But we cannot know since we don't have a clue what your `cv_ver_names` exactly looks like.

Comment: Yes, sure.. is some information missing.
Ok, I can now parsed this variable. `keep_count` var is correct but it does not represent a key of dict but rather a slice of last element. `keep_qry` retrieve the first x elements of the list `cv_ver_names`, ex.: `cv_ver_name[:5]` . I muss probably find a another way to retrieve first elements of this list...